# If you have to put breaks in the if statements, why do we need to bother with conditions in the while operation?

Tags: c, if-statement, do-while

This is just a general question really.

I wrote this originally

```
    do
    {
        scanf("%i", &Carselect);
        if (Carselect == 1)
        {
            mass = 1100;
            velomax = 200;
        }
        else if (Carselect == 2)
        {
            mass = 1888;
            velomax = 415
        }
        else if (Carselect == 3)
        {
            mass = 18000;
            velomax = 129;
        }
        else
        {
        printf("Error in input. Please enter 1, 2 or 3.\n");
        }
    }
    while (Carselect != 1 || Carselect != 2 || Carselect != 3);
```

And I got stuck in the loop. I put breaks in the statements for the valid conditions and that allowed me to get out, like this

```
    do
    {
        scanf("%i", &Carselect);
        if (Carselect == 1)
        {
            mass = 1100;
            velomax = 200;
            break;
        }
        else if (Carselect == 2)
        {
            mass = 1888;
            velomax = 415;
            break;
        }
        else if (Carselect == 3)
        {
            mass = 18000;
            velomax = 129;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
        printf("Error in input. Please enter 1, 2 or 3.\n");
        }
    }
    while (Carselect != 1 || Carselect != 2 || Carselect != 3);
```

but I thought that the conditions for while were repeat conditions, so as soon as Carselect equals 1, 2 or 3 it will exit the loop. If you have to put breaks in the if statements, why do we need to bother with conditions in the while operation?

What is there, on the machine level or otherwise, that requires this seemingly trivial bit of logic?

Comment: Seriously? I was putting an AND condition rather than an OR? Shoot me now please
Yeah, that worked

Comment: Look at the title. Look at valid code in working programs/examples. Look at the title again. Why is the title wrong?

Comment: Hmm. Possible revised title: "While condition not working--had to use break". Is that better? Can you be more specific with your critique, @user2864740?

Comment: `break` and `continue` are generally considered bad style because the flow can be difficult to follow, resulting in spaghetti code.  Some programming standards do not allow them (except with statements like `select`).  My view is that they can avoid convoluted code and are sometimes justified.  But only sometimes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edit (as the question's title is changed):**

The checking condition in the while/do-while loop is the one that is primarily checked to determine if the program is to stay in or to get out of the while/do-while loop - not the break statement.

The break statement is normally used if:

1. you want to get out of the while/do-while block **before** it is executing every statement in the block or
2. when certain **exceptional termination condition** is reached before you loop through your entire loop iteration or
3. You create an **infinite loop** and you capture an **error** which makes you unable to continue the loop or
4. Some other other cases which I might not be aware of...

Essentially, break-statement is **not** normally used to terminate the while/do-while block as long as the program follows (for lack of better term) **"standard/main" path** in the loop block.

In contrast, **condition** in the while/do-while loop **is** used to terminate the loop when the program **follows** "standard/main" path in the loop block.

**Original:**

You should change your inequality check (`!=`) into `NOT` equality check (`==`).

```
while (!(Carselect == 1 || Carselect == 2 || Carselect == 3));
```

This is because what you really want is for the loop to continue as long as

> the Carselect is not (1 or 2 or 3)

Alternatively, you could change the or operator (`||`) to and operator (`&&`) which results in the same logic:

```
while (Carselect != 1 && Carselect != 2 && Carselect != 3);
```

> the Carselect is not 1 and not 2 and not 3

Comment: Indeed. ('Not 1 OR not 2 OR not 3' is always going to be true.)

Comment: I was thinking about it backwards.

Comment: @EurekaKN backwards? As in?

Comment: I was thinking of it like an OR gate, I want 1 or 2 or 3 that's how I would have ideal like to have written it. So with out thinking I didn't consider that 1' or 2' or 3' could mean any value.

Comment: @EurekaKN ah, I think I get it... ;)

Answer (score 0):

In C **break** takes you to the statement immediately following } of the containing block, and **continue** takes you to to the statement immediately following { of the containing block.  Both are useful in a long block, for example if an error condition occurs, or if a simpler input is detected, and not all the processing of the complete block is required, but you want to *continue* and get the next input.

Comment: If you are using **else** twice the **switch/case** construct is more readable.

Comment: Respectfully suggest (1) that as per comments on the question itself, this was an incorrectly-thought-out while condition, and (2) that the loop here is for catching invalid input and is not a main loop.